# TileStache PNG Optimization

Tags: tiles, png, tilestache, compression, optimization

A [Tilestache config](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Core.html) file has a "png options" object that passes its config straight through to the Python Imaging Library (PIL). Setting `optimize: true` does some kind of optimization as the file is being written by PIL. I've found that using tools like **optipng** or **pngout** can yield further optimization.

Is there some hook I can use, or a way to tell Tilestache to run optipng and pngout on the tiles once they're cached?

I found a tool called **picopt** that does this sort of thing; I could run it on the cache folder, but I'd like to know how I can have Tilestache do this automatically.

Or, if I'm barking up the wrong tree, what's the best practice for optimizing map tiles?